# Not able to get value from postman response body

Tags: javascript, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have an API which has response as below:

```
"message": "Success!",
    "user": {
        "id": 17,
        "first_name_kanji_or_hiragana": "Hiragana",
        "last_name_kanji_or_hiragana": "Name",
        "first_name_katakana": null,
        "last_name_katakana": null,
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "image_path": null,
        "email_verified_at": "2019-03-06 04:44:46",
        "type": "admin",
        "created_at": "2019-03-06 04:44:46",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-06 04:44:46",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "full_name": "Name Hiragana",
        "full_image_path": null,
        "roles": [
```

Each time when i am running the API new user `id` is generating. What i want to do is that i want to fetch the id each time i run the api & then want to use that id in next response.
I have used below code to fetch the id but it's not working

```
pm.test(responseBody, true)
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
jsonData.data.user[0].id
```

Comment: The above json doesn't seems to have array of user so your code should be 
  'jsonData.data.user.id' instead of 'jsonData.data.user[0].id'

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.test(responseBody, true)
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
jsonData.data.user[0].id // youre access the user if its array its not
```

Just use `jsonData.data.user.id` or `jsonData.data.user[id]`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an array called user

> jsonData.data.user[0].id

But user is an object, so you need to access:
jsonData.data.user.id

There are sometimes that you need to check the complete json directly from your request.

Answer (score 0):

`user` is not an array. Try the below one.

`jsonData.data.user.id`

Your solution will work when you have the JSON like below,

```
    "lib_folders": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 5,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1549608521.3831923,
                "ctime": 1548742613.5470872,
                "path": "/root/abc/xyz",
                "xusr": true
            },
            {
                "atime": 1549608521.4031928,
                "ctime": 1548742462.3279672,
                "path": "/root/123/456",
                "xusr": true
            }
        ],
        "matched": 2,
        "msg": ""
    }
```

For the above JSON if you want to get the `path` of the first file, then use the below code,

`jsonData.data.lib_folders.files[0].path`